# Set scrollTop and scrollLeft without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, scrolltop

I have a question about the `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` properties. I would like to set these properties in my div without using JavaScript (jQuery). Is this possible?

My problem is, I have a program which interprets the HTML code and the divs which I scrolled have the value zero when the program interpret the code. The program can't read the `scrollTop` or `scrollLeft` value. Exists a HTML-tag like:

```
<div scrollLeft="300" scrollTop="200"></div>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is not possible using CSS/HTML only.

### Edit [05.01.2012] - A possible solution

I created a solution that works in the following browsers:

- Firefox 4+
- Safari 5+
- Chrome 6+
- Opera 11+
- IE 10+
- Android 2.3+

It's really a bit hacky, so see whether you would use it or not. :)

**A little explanation**

I used the HTML5 attribute `autofocus` on an `<input>`-field. As this will focus the input, it has to get it into the viewport. Therefor it will scroll to the given position. To get rid of the highlighted outline and to not see the input at all, you have to set some styles. But this still forced Safari to have one blinking pixel, so I did the trick with the span, that acts like an overlay. Note that you can't simply use `display: none` as this won't trigger the autofocus (only tested this in Safari).

**Demo**

The demo will run in Safari and Chrome only. IE and Firefox seem to not fire autofocus in an `<iframe>`.

```css
div.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}

div.inner>input {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 300px;
  left: 200px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

div.inner>span {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 300px;
  left: 200px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <input type="text" autofocus></input>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could make a container that behaves like a scrollable container while its parent has "overflow:hidden"-attribute. This way you can easily set margin (e. g. in inline-style attr) to have the pre-scroll effect.

Comment: @xcy7e웃 Could you create a fiddle to demonstrate it or add your solution as an possible answer.

Comment: any way to pre-scroll multiple elements with this technique?  (no iframes, though that will work in webkit only anyway)

Comment: There is no need for a `span` on top of the input, just set the input to `opacity: 0`