# Overflow:scroll; Is there a way to default scroll to selected value onload?

Tags: css, overflow

I have a dropdown menu that users can select values from. It is currently generated with a table, where each option is a  in the table. I know using an  element would be better, but changing to that at this point would require a lot of work.

The dropdown menu shows 6 rows, and uses "overflow: scroll" to allow the user to scroll down to see the rest of the options.

Currently, when the user selects the dropdown, the scroll bar always starts at the top and they have to scroll down to the bottom of the list if they want to select one of those rows.

What I want is a way to have the scroll bar start at the element they previously selected. I know the row number the user has previously selected, and can use that to calculate the number of pixels the scroll bar should be moved down on load.

The specific HTML code is not too important, because I believe this idea can be generalized to a lot of situations, but here is what I am working with right now: Some of the elements are missing because they are dynamically generated at run time, but you should be able to get the general idea of what I am working with.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%;>
    <colgroup>
    <col class="select_htc_col" style="font-size: 11px;">
</colgroup>
    <tbody>
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
            <tr style="height: 19px;">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I feel like there should be some CSS property to have the scroll bar not start at the top.

Another idea would be to give each  an ID, and use to show the element somehow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't achieve that with pure CSS. Please check: [set scrollTop and scrollLeft without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139091/set-scrolltop-and-scrollleft-without-javascript).

You can do it with jQuery, it has a `scrollTop()` function. Also that function has an int parameter as well to indicate/set the position to scroll.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>scrollTop demo</title>
        <style>
            p {
                margin: 10px;
                padding: 5px;
                border: 2px solid #666;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p></p> 
        <script>
            var p = $( "p:first" );
            $( "p:last" ).text( "scrollTop:" + p.scrollTop() );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Taken from: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have no problem using javascript if that is the easiest way. I will give this a try.