# overflow scroll, start at the bottom, scroll up

Tags: html, css

I have a simple chat section in my app similar to texting/iMessage. How can I have overflow hidden, but starting at the bottom and scroll up? Is there anyway to do this without JS?

Comment: Scrolling up without JS isn't possible I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

This task requires you to initially set the `scrollTop` position *and it's necessary to use JS to do the job*. I don't think using CSS alone would fit your need.

See this:
[set scrollTop and scrollLeft without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139091/set-scrolltop-and-scrollleft-without-javascript)