# Animated side-menu with rollover images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to recreate an animated side-menu with rollover images inspired by [this live example](https://goo.gl/lvPMR5).

I have the following code and wanted to know if there is any possibility to link the menu, to rollover presentation images like we have in the above shown example and how. Any thoughts?

```css
body {
    font: normal 1.0em Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #A8CBFF;
}

nav {
    font-size: 3.0em;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    color: white;
    
    width:6em;
    height: 9.0em;

    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    left: -4.5em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 1.0em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    position: relative;

    border-top-right-radius: 0.75em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.75em;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms, background-color 500ms, color 500ms;
    transition: transform 500ms, background-color 500ms, color 500ms;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(1) { background-color: #00aced;}
nav ul li:nth-child(2) { background-color: #3b5998;}
nav ul li:nth-child(3) { background-color: #517fa4;}
nav ul li:nth-child(4) { background-color: #007bb6;}
nav ul li:nth-child(5) { background-color: #cb2027;}
nav ul li:nth-child(6) { background-color: #ea4c89;}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #C1232D;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(4.5em);
    transform: translateX(4.5em);
}

nav ul li span {
    display:block;
    font-family: Arial;
    position: absolute;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    height:1.0em;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    right: 0.16666666666667em;
    color: #F8F6FF;
}

a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com">Category 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Category 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a div with a hidden overflow, and using an animated .scrollTop. See this fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Domination/nezwu0ye/9/

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li name='cat1'><a href="http://www.twitter.com">Category 1</a></li>
    <li name='cat2'><a href="http://www.facebook.com">Category 2</a></li>
    <li name='cat3'><a href="http://www.instagram.com">Category 3</a></li>
  </ul>
    <div id='menuRight'>
       <div>
           stufffss
           <img src='http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/mediumsize/PIA17011_ip.jpg'>
           </img>
       </div>
      <div>
          More stufffss
          <img src='http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg'>
          </img>
      </div>
      <div>
          Even more stufffss
          <img src='http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31100000/random-space-space-31155586-598-398.jpg'>
          </img>
      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font: normal 1.0em Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #A8CBFF;
}

nav {
    font-size: 3.0em;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    color: white;

    width:6em;
    height: 9.0em;

    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    left: -4.5em;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 1.0em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    position: relative;

    border-top-right-radius: 0.75em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.75em;

    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms, background-color 500ms, color 500ms;
    transition: transform 500ms, background-color 500ms, color 500ms;
}

nav ul li:nth-child(1) { background-color: #00aced;}
nav ul li:nth-child(2) { background-color: #3b5998;}
nav ul li:nth-child(3) { background-color: #517fa4;}
nav ul li:nth-child(4) { background-color: #007bb6;}
nav ul li:nth-child(5) { background-color: #cb2027;}
nav ul li:nth-child(6) { background-color: #ea4c89;}

nav ul li.hovered {
    background-color: #C1232D;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(4.5em);
    transform: translateX(4.5em);
}

nav ul li span {
    display:block;
    font-family: Arial;
    position: absolute;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    height:1.0em;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    right: 0.16666666666667em;
    color: #F8F6FF;
}

a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*new*/
#menuRight{
    height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    left:250px;
}
#menuRight div{
    height:100%;
}
#menuRight img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

JS:

```
var height, index, prevIndex

$('nav ul li').mouseover(function(){
    //Set the aesthetics (similar to :hover)
    $('nav ul li').removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).addClass('hovered');

    //Gets relevant data required for scrolling of menuRight    
    height = $("#menuRight").css("height").replace('px','');
    index = $(this).index();

    //If the category button (from the navlist) has changed
    if (index != prevIndex){
        $("#menuRight").stop(); //Stop animation queues
        $("#menuRight").animate({"scrollTop":height*index}, 400, 'easeOutBounce');
        prevIndex = index;
    }
});
```

To install jQuery UI (required for easing), include this in your HTML  tags:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that's it except one thing, in `css` we have the possibility to use `ease-in-out` options & stuff. Is there any possibility to set these parameters in `js` code too? I think that in the live example this rollover trick is made with pure `css` but not so sure, I can't find any `js` file related.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using pure CSS for this example. It [can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139091/set-scrolltop-and-scrollleft-without-javascript) be done, but using jQuery is much more browser compatible. As for easing, if you use jQuery UI, you can include an easing parameter at the end of .animate(). See edited answer above :)

Comment: Easing options can be found here:
https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a good place to start. is there any possibility to find out if my theme or wordpress have already jquery UI implemented? I guess that I have to install UI because I can't find it in the console. There is only `jquery.js`. http://goo.gl/xGBMtI

Comment: I'm not sure if it's already implemented, but I guess you could try running the code and seeing if you get an error? You should get an Uncaught TypeError if it isn't installed.

I'm quite unfamiliar with themes, but if you include this in your <head> tags in HTML you should be OK.

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figured it out :) I really appreciate it!

Comment: if someone will find useful, I've figured it out, it works like a charm in codepen, we just have to insert in settings/ stuff for <head> section `jquery` and `jquery-ui` scripts: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` and 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`.Here's the codepen with visible `easeOutBounce` effect http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPBEXP .

Comment: Hey there @D Slee, I have a question regarding your answer.Is there any possibility to make the images slide from left to right for example? I've tried to replace `scrollTop` with `scrollLeft` but it doesn't work. Any toughts? Thank you.

Comment: There are ways, however scrolling from left to right is more difficult, since the layout of HTML is generally from top to bottom, with the exception of tables and floating elements. The principle of using a hidden overflow can be applied similarly to generate the sliding in effect, as per this example (using absolute positioning within the relative frame #menuRight): https://jsfiddle.net/nezwu0ye/13/

This example basically forces the slides to be in their set positions, with the slides being drawn off screen and pushed into screen as required :)

Comment: This is freaking amazing. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Is it too much if I ask about right-to-left? I thought it's the same changing `scrollLeft` with `scrollRight` but .. not really. Any thoughts? pure educational I'm curious :)

Comment: Yeah you can scroll right to left, you just have to invert their positions and scroll positioning accordingly. There is no scrollRight() function in jquery (which is annoying). However, scrollRight(x) is equivalent to scrollLeft(width-x). Since the children of #menuRight have absolute positioning, the width of #menuRight is not the total scrolling width, and hence we must calculate it manually. Additionally, when scrolling, you need to find the inverted scrolling positionn, as per initial offset inversion. Anyway, if that made no sense, here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/nezwu0ye/14/).

Comment: D Slee, that was a good lesson in jQuery, thank you for your time, I really appreciate it! :) right-to-left images in this context it looks more natural.