# CSS top, then scroll back to the top

Tags: html, css, image, reactjs, scroll

I have this code running with react js

```
<div style={{width:width, height:'1000px',overflowX:'hidden',overflowY:'scroll'}}>
  <img src={img} style={{position:'relative', top:top, left:left, zoom:zoom+'%'}}/>
</div>
```

The variable top is a negative number. This allows me to start displaying the image at a certain height. And I can scroll down to the bottom of the image. However I cannot fully scroll all the way back up to the top of the image (not the initial position).Any ideas on how to allow that?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `scrollTop` property of the `<div>` instead of the `top`. You need JavaScript for this.

```
element.scrollTop = <your variable (positive)>
```

If for some reason you want only CSS, you can check [set scrollTop and scrollLeft without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14139091/set-scrolltop-and-scrollleft-without-javascript)